# secure the code in google chrome extension

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a google chrome extension, that should make a request to my website to send and get some data, so, actually I should do an ajax request like it is written here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.example.com/data.json", true);
```

I wanted ask if there is a way to somehow secure the code or prevent others from using my api, because actually the other users can see the source code of the extension when they install it and so use my api without me being aware of it.

**EDIT:**

If I need to make some sort of authentication, than how can I authenticate the user before making the ajax call ? for authentication I will need to send a request to my server , but for that I should send , e.g. username and password, that should be saved somewhere in the extension's files, which, in fact, can be seen by the users, when they install the extension.

Thanks

Comment: You expose a public api in a chrome extension - and you do not want other users of the extension to use it? What's the meaning of the api then?

Comment: you could identify your user using google chrome authentication api and store some stuff on your side to ensure the user has the right. See this google doc; http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html

Comment: @madflow, what if I want my api to by used only by authorized people, is not there a meaning in that ?

Comment: Thanks @Happyninja, I will review the doc

Comment: @Davo - if you want your API to be usable only by authorized people then you need to include some sore of authentification schema...  If for example you assume that all connections are authorized then of course you have a flaw.  Perhaps look into oAuth and use tokens.  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't trust the browser, take steps to authenticate the **user** instead.  So, in this case, you could require that YOU enter in a password that is used to communicate with your server.

Your Google extension would simple require you to enter in a password before it attempts to use AJAX to communicate with your server.

Be aware that you should build in means of protecting yourself from brute-force attacks.  So, do things like lock everything down if there are more than some small number of wrong passwords, etc.

You could also consider using the password to simply decrypt the destination of the XHR, but if you go this route, you should store this very carefully, because this will be brute-forceable offline.

**EDIT**
Trying to lock down an API so that only a single application can use it is just not practical nor technically possible, so you're only hope of doing this is to authenticate the user using the API, regardless of the accessing software he is using.  You could have the user sign an agreement that legally limits them to only your extension, but I suspect this will go largely unenforceable and will consume your time tracking abusers down.

If you don't want unauthorized people even knowing where the API is, you could perform authentication using an out-of-band mechanism: over the telephone, email, SMS, or simply, another API that will grant the user a password or token that requests to your API must be accompanied with.

During this out-of-band process, you could also grant the user, a unique URI (the API access point) that is only valid per authenticated session (https://api.totally-cool-extension.com/api/ijyeDvB5dYvSiWG97OLuTAoNWwbhuZ0/, for example).  Any requests to your server on OTHER URIs simply won't work.  However, this isn't theoretically much different than using the same API access point, and having a good password.  It just changes the number of places in your architecture that will be performing authentication and/or authorization checks.

`<aside>`My vote would be to reduce the number of authorization/authentication points to as few as possible so that you can spend more time on getting that one place correct rather than having multiple places and possibly multiple logic flaws or other things that could lead to vulnerabilities.`</aside>`

You could also explore using Public Key Infrastructure and/or one-time passwords schemes or device-based token generators, etc., but in the end, you'll be allowing authenticated and authorized users to use your API. And, thanks to the Internet, this will not remain an undisclosed URI for long.

And, more importantly, it will not prevent someone from using the data on their own.  Even with all these measures in place, it would be trivial for an authorized user to collect this data as it is being streamed to your extension.  Or, if you employ point-to-point encryption, they could screen-scrap or use some form of JS introspection on your very code or even extract the data from their computer's memory.

I know you were looking for a silver bullet here, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: but how can I authenticate the user before making a ajax call ? for authentication I will need to send a request to my server , right ? but for that I should send , e.g. username and password, that should be saved somewhere in the extension's files, which is , in fact, can be seen by the users, when they install the extension, right ?

Comment: Update answer to address that question.

Comment: Thanks @mkoistinen, and you are right, I was looking for a silver bullet, Thanks !

Comment: But how would an example google oauthentication work on extension. Cause google OAuth identified via tokens (Change everytime). Thus, token in chrome extension API would differ than website OAuth. Please visit my SO question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66191910/securing-chrome-extension-google-calendar-api-calls-to-website

Answer (score 4):

I think you are doing it wrong. You should never trust what's going on on internet users PC's. Never!

Move the line of trust one step inward, make your API public and then design the security where you have perfect control - server side.

Comment: but if the api is public so anyone can send and get the data, how do I secure it in the server side ? I want to be sure that only those people can use api who, say, have a key, but if I put a key in the extension, it is visible and not secure, Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I could not get correct aspect of your use case

**Few Points:**

- Your extension code is **`always`** traceable( Any one who has installed extension can view the code)
- If you are looking for security through **`complicated or obfuscated coding patterns`** you end up slow down of understanding process not the whole.
- If your target is to ensure users who install your extension should be able to access and inert all other users( Who have gained illegal access or downloaded and edited code) have a **session shared key** per installation.

Please explain further use case so i can help you better.

Comment: my target is to be sure that after creating the extension no one can viewing my code in extension somehow be able to make a request from some other website to my website, or create other extension like that and use that my make a request to my website, does my comment make sense ? Thanks