# Securing the API exposed in chrome extension

Tags: api, security, google-chrome-extension

**Current State :**

I am working on a chrome extension. My extension makes a request to my web-server and shows the results fetched.

**Disadvantages :**

1. I am exposing my APIs, so any third-party , not necessarily, owner of the extension may make a number of requests on my server. This will allow him access to all my data
2. This can also lead to my server crash, if the requests are made very frequently via bots.

So, is there any way that can authorize that requests made to the corresponding server handles are via the chrome extension only. Can it be done by setting some cookie and checking them before sending results ?

Thanks !

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763103/secure-the-code-in-google-chrome-extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not ensure that only your Chrome extension is making the requests.  Once your code leaves your control (i.e. the client has it), there is no guarantee that it isn't tampered with or reverse engineered.  What you can do though, is make the user log in before accessing your API.

By authenticating, you aren't verifying that the user is using your Chrome extension, but you do have someone to blacklist if your server becomes the subject of large traffic.  You can have the user of the chrome extension create an account one time and then the extension can send those credentials to your server with each request.

You may be tempted to try things like embedding a secret token or passphrase, but this will only stop the lazy attackers.  Furthermore it may give you a false sense of security.  Go with authentication if you are worried about Denial of Service attacks.